# Relative difference between elements in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I need the difference `x2 - x1` *n* times for each element in the first column of an (n, 3) array, in order to yield an (n, n) array. Meaning, I need:

```
[0,0] - [0,0], [1,0] - [0,0], [2,0] - [0,0],...[n,0] - [0,0]
[0,0] - [1,0], [1,0] - [1,0], [2,0] - [1,0],...[n,0] - [0,0]
                             :
[0,0] - [n,0], [1,0] - [n,0], [2,0] - [n,0],...[n,0] - [n,0]
```

I have tried `numpy.diff(a[:,0])`, though this only yields the difference between the directly neighbouring elements, i.e. `[1,0] - [0,0], [2,0] - [1,0],...[n,0] - [n-1,0]`.

Comment: I don't really understand the Question. so you need the difference of all the columns

Comment: I need the difference between the first element and all other elements, the difference between the second element and all other elements, the difference between the third element and all other elements, etc.

So for example for the array

`[[5 2 4]
[3 9 8]
[8 3 7]]`

I need `5 - 5`, `3 - 5`, `8 - 5`, and `5 - 3`, `3 - 3`, `8 - 3`, and `5 - 8`, `3 - 8`, `8 - 8`.

Giving a new (3, 3) array 

`[[0 -2 3]
[2 0 5]
[-3 -5 0]]` 

I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely do not use three nested for loops for problems like these.

To be honest, I don't quite understand your final goal, but IIUC, you may use broadcasting

```
(a - a[:, None])[..., 0]
```

which yields

```
array([[ 0, -2,  3],
       [ 2,  0,  5],
       [-3, -5,  0]])
```

If you want to do the same operation for the second column, just use `[..., 1]` etc.

---

If you just really need this operation in the first column only (and not on the others), calculating everything and then extracting the first result can be overkill. You might just then slice first, and subtract using broadcasting

```
f = a[:, 0]
f - f[:, None]
```

Answer (score -1):

So, the problem formulation is a bit confusing, it would have been nice to have the example in the comments in the original question, along with a more mathematical formulation.

You can probably do it with `numpy`, but it seemed so specific that I stuck to using only `list`s instead. Here is how you could do it using your comment's example:

```py
import numpy as np

ex = [
    [5, 2, 4], 
    [3, 9, 8], 
    [8, 3, 7]
]

ex_as_np_array = np.array(ex)
rows, cols = ex_as_np_array.shape[0], ex_as_np_array.shape[1]

# Forcing in order to only get the results for the first column
# Otherwise the result is going to be (9, 3) or (nrows*ncols, nrows).
cols = 1

result = []
for row in range(0, rows):
    for col in range(0, cols):

        row_result = []
        for i in range(0, rows):

            operation = ex[i][col] - ex[row][col]
            row_result.append(operation)

        result.append(row_result)    

result_as_np_array = np.array(result)
```

Which gives:

```
Result:
[[ 0 -2  3]
 [ 2  0  5]
 [-3 -5  0]]

Shape:
(3, 3)
```